# Specifying a member function as a callback in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have the following:

```
typedef std::function<bool (const std::string&)> SomethingCoolCb;

class ClassA
{
public:
    void OnSomethingCool(const SomethingCoolCb& cb)
    {
        _cb = cb;
    }

private:
    SomethingCoolCb _cb;
};

class ClassB
{
public:
    ClassB();
    bool Juggle(const std::string& arg);

private:
    ClassA _obj;
};
```

and I want to specify the ClassB::Juggle() member function as the callback to ClassB::_obj.  Would the proper way to do that in C++11 be (in ClassB's constructor):

```
ClassB::ClassB()
{
    _obj.OnDoSomethingCool(
        [&](const std::string& arg) -> bool
        {
            return Juggle(arg);
        });
}
```

From what I understand, the compiler will make a std::function object out of the above lambda code.  So when the callback gets invoked, it'll call the std::function::operator() member and then it'll invoke ClassB::Juggle() instead of invoking ClassB::Juggle() directly.  Unless I'm mistaken about what happens under the covers, that all seems to be a little inefficient.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Beware that capturing `this` in a lambda (as in your example) does not work well with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 6):

Only use `std::function` if you really need polymorphic functions. Otherwise make it a template.

To adapt a member function to a functor use `std::mem_fn` and then `bind` an object to the first argument, the resulting functor can serve as your callback.

Sample:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>

template<typename F>
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA(F f) : _cb(f) {}

private:
    F _cb;
};

class ClassB
{
public:
    ClassB() 
  : _obj(std::bind(&ClassB::Juggle, this, 
                   std::placeholders::_1)) 
  {}
  bool Juggle(const std::string& arg) {return true;}
private:
    ClassA<decltype(std::bind(
                      std::declval<bool (ClassB::*)(const std::string&)>()
                      , std::declval<ClassB*>()
                      , std::placeholders::_1
                      ) ) > _obj;
};

int main()
{
  ClassB b;
  return 0;
}
```

This side-steps the cost of function at the cost of being horribly ugly.

Comment: The bind() syntax always made me a little queezy with the _1, _2, _3, etc. placeholder parameters and what not.  I figured that now that C++ has lambdas, bind() was obsolete.  But since bind() is out of Boost and now part of the standard, perhaps I was mistaken with that assumption.

Comment: @ArcadioAlivioSincero `bind` can still be useful. Sometimes it is shorter as well. I've updated the example to side-step `function` with a little trickery.

Comment: Callbacks are usually a good place to use `std::function<>`s for flexibility (considering that a *function* can be used to register *any type* of callback, you need something uniform to store it into)

Comment: @pmr that's a nice example.  i especially like how you show how to use the new decltype keyword in there.  I will keep that in mind in case I will ever find a use for it.  Unfortunately, I think that'd make even some of the most seasoned C++ developers stab themselves in the eye with a spork if they had to maintain that code ;).

Comment: @ArcadioAlivioSincero Job security measures and all that ;) Go with David's solution and use `std::function`. Optimize this part if your callbacks are really too slow.